# Transform image in webp and get srcset

Tags: image-transforms

Is possible from a jpg image from an entry field return a serset in webp fomat?
Something like:

```
<source type="image/webp" srcset="800w webp image, 1200w webp image ">
```

Because I can convert in web or get the srcset from the original image
but I don't know how to convert the original image and get a srcset.

Thanks in advance and kind regards,
Davide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can – assets include a [`getSrcSet` method](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html#method-getsrcset) which will generate all the requested image sizes and return a `srcset` string. This method accepts an [image transform](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/image-transforms.html#defining-transforms-in-your-templates) which can include the desired output format.

```twig
{% set image = entry.someImageField.one() %}
{% set webpTransform = {
    format: 'webp',
    quality: 75,
} %}
<source type="image/webp" srcset="{{ image.getSrcSet([800, 1200], webpTransform) }}">
```

Note that in order for this to work, your server needs to have either GD or ImageMagick installed with WebP support.

Check out the documentation on [Image Transforms](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/image-transforms.html) for more information.

Comment: Great, it works perfectly! 
Thanks for the support!

Regards,
Davide